# Difficulty with settings in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1). I recently installed Android Studio on my PC and doing so messed up some of my Eclipse settings, even though I installed Studio in completely different directories.

Now when I run Eclipse, I am getting the error message: 'Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK'C:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk'

Moving this project to Studio is not an option at this time.

But there's no 'tools'directory anywhere in the adt-bundle or sdk directories. There is a 'build-tools' directory and a 'platform-tools' but no just 'tools' and I don't recall there being one. Eclipse is hell-bent on finding a tools directory that doesn't exist.

How can I direct Eclipse to look elsewhere? I have attached screencaps from the preferences and also the directories from Windows Explorer.

Thanks for any help. Would be greatly appreciated.[Directories[image: ][1]]

Comment: try re-downloading the SKD and reconfiguring where Eclipse is looking for it.

Comment: OK. I'll try that. Should I delete the SDK that's currently on the hard drive?

Comment: glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found an easy solution.

I simply copied the tools directory and everything in it from my Android Studio sdk directory to my Eclipse sdk directory. It works fine now.

I think Steve's suggestion would have worked too. But this was easier.

For some reason, when I installed Android Studio on my machine, it deleted the \sdk\tools\ directory and everything in it. Don't know why!